# ASP.NET Core CreateAsync raises ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create 50 seed user accounts in my ASP.NET Core app, but after the first call to `_userManager.CreateAsync`, `_userManager` is disposed.  To me, my code looks the same as the Register code from the Account controller.

My code:

```
var generatedUsers = await GetRandomUsers();
foreach (var generatedUser in generatedUsers)
{
    var newUser = new ApplicationUser
    {
        UserName = generatedUser.Email,
        Email = generatedUser.Email,
        DisplayUserName = "Boo"
    };

    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser,"123Abc!");
}
```

And here is the relevant Register code from AccountController.cs that works repeatedly:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, DisplayUserName = model.DisplayUserName};
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

After the first call, my `CreateAsync` returns success and the database has the new user record.  By the second time through the loop `_userManager` is disposed.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Where/how is `_userManager` defined?

Comment: Are you `await`ing the method that generates your random users (i.e. the 'My code' bit) properly?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari the _userManager is just the standard user manager that is injected into the controller.  I think it just comes with the asp.net auth system as normal.

Comment: @GregHNZ I am awaiting the GetRandomUsers function, yes.  That function just calls https://randomuser.me/api to retrieve a bunch of random user data and returns it.

Comment: @GregHNZ I tried changing my GetRandomUsers function to simply return a list of hard-coded objects.  No awaiting required, yet I still get the ObjectDisposedException.

Comment: This might be a hint:  Before the line 

var data = await client.GetStringAsync("https://randomuser.me/api");

The userManager is NOT disposed, but right after it, it has been disposed.  client is an HttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

After a long investigation, I figured it out:

Since I am "awaiting" async processes then the main request completes and the UserManager is disposed before the awaited intermediate operations finish -- such as my HttpClient requests or my user creation activities.  UserManager lifetime is apparently per-request.

Comment: You can have _userManager live throughout the whole controller method call, so this is not the cause.

Comment: You may want to share with us how you instantiate the _userManager in the controller, there may be an issue there